# Veeam free fails to create or open file

Tags: powershell, vmware, veeam

I have a VMWare environment that i want to backup. i am using the freeware version of Veeam backup and replication. I want to run the backup from the cli and then ultimately use task scheduler, when i try to run the  following command

```
Find-VBRViEntity -Name badges | Start-VBRZip -Folder "b:\"
```

B: is a viable location, its a mounted network share.
 however i get the following error in the Veeam console log.

```
12/16/2016 4:00:35 PM :: Processing Badges Error: The system cannot find the path specified.Failed to create or open file [b:\Badges2016-12-16T160033.vbk].
```

I am running the above by opening powershell as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work with a share mounted as network drive. Use UNC path or iSCSI if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It will work with such folder, if it's mounted under system account or exactly under user, which is used by Veeam on this server to access the file system.

Basically, shares, that are mounted as network drive, are not visible out of context of user, which was used to mount them (cause Network mapped drives are located in HKCU\Network. The letters under Network are the drive letters)

Solution: use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx), to run cmd and net use under system account.